# Calibrating Adafruit TCS34725 for RGB colors

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, adafruit

I am new to Arduino. I am currently working on a project which requires color detection using the TCS34725 Adafruit sensor module.
For the project, I need to calibrate the sensor with RGB colors. Color patches of RGB will be exposed to the sensor. After exposing each color patch, a push button will be pressed and then the calibration for that color should start.

1. Calibrate for Red
2. Calibrate for Green
3. Calibrate for Blue

After calibration, the sensor needs to detect the colors of objects.
I have no idea what is meant by calibrating the sensor for RGB values. Can someone please be kind enough to explain it to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It means exposing a known color with known lighting and using the returned sensor data to define that data as, e.g., "red". Subsequent "unknown" colors can then use the calibration data to attempt to identify unknown colors. You might want to check out the [Learning Guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-color-sensors/overview) which also includes a link discussing (roughly) this topic.

Comment: your question is off topic here because it is unrelated to the arduino